# Uploading files using the Postman binary method to asp.net MVC controller cannot receive files?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

In the Postman tool, using the Form-data method to upload files to asp.net MVC controller can receive files normally, but using the binary method to upload file controller Action method Request.Files Unable to receive the file, excuse me where is the mistake?

For example, controller action:

```
public class UploadFilesController : Controller
{
    // GET: UploadFiles
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Test()
    {
        if (Request.Files.Count > 0)
        {
            var file = Request.Files[0];

            return Json("OK! Received file");
        }
        else
        {
            return Json("No file Received");
        }


    }
}
```

The following is the Postman binary method upload file icon:

[image]

[image]

Comment: try adding the following header: `Content-Type: multipart/form-data;`

Comment: try adding the following header: Content-Type: multipart/form-data;
of no effect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think that it's possible to send the image/file as `binary` from postman, and have it readable in `Request.Files` in your controller action.

If you open the postman console (<kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> or View -> Show Postman Console), you can see the request data, as well as the response.

Sending a file in the *normal* fashion, using form data, you can see that the body of the request has a lot of information about the file:

[image: postman form data post request]

When sending a file using the binary method, the request body is undefined:

[image: postman binary post request]

So, when the request is received by the controller, it doesn't know how to interpret this undefined data. I'm not saying that it's *impossible* to extract the file from the raw input stream, but there's a lot of data that's posted in the form data, that **isn't** posted in binary, that helps the controller to understand the request.

Answer (score 2):

As you have not set Content-Type explicitly, Postman set default Content-Type. For form-data type of body, Postman sets Content-Type to multipart/form-data. And it does not set Content-Type for binary method. But in a binary type, the file attached must be binary in nature i.e. not human-readable. It seems that your file is human readable and hence your request is not processed as you are expecting.

You can refer below link for default Content-Type in different cases.

[text/plain is the default value for textual files. A textual file should be human-readable and must not contain binary data. application/octet-stream is the default value for all other cases.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Basics_of_HTTP/MIME_types/Common_types)

Sending request using Postman - [click here](https://learning.postman.com/docs/postman/sending-api-requests/requests/#binary-data)